# Make command error for building Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, customization

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
build/core/host_shared_library_internal.mk:51: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libart.so' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libart.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Please give me the solution of this problem.

Source code downloaded 
after that i am doing make -j4 or make :- please help
OS :- 16.04 Ununtu